# Connect sequel pro to db on another networked computer

Tags: networking, mysql, sequel-pro

I have a local network computer that is set up to run php etc and can be accessed using host names such as mysite.dev etc all works well.

At the moment the php server / computer uses workbench to connect and do stuff, but it would be nice to enable it so that computers/macs on the local network can use their db program like sequel pro etc to connect to.

i have added the details as requested and using the host ip 192.168.1.54 but when testing the connection i get  the usual details and

```
   MySQL said: Can't connect to MySQL server on '192.168.1.54' (4)...
```

Is there anything i need to do on the host computer to let these access them or something else to the firewall etc.

Comment: Windows, Linux, Mac?

Comment: The main machin eis Windows 7 then the other machines connecting are macs and pc's